# angularjs ng-change directive deactivation when switched between pages or view

Tags: angularjs-directive

The below code works fine until I am present in the same page.
If I switch between pages, the checkbox which are active remain the same.
But I want to deactivate it when view or page is switched.

I even tried emptying the array updateDataList. But there are no changes.

In HTML

```
<td>
    <input name ="chk1[]" type="checkbox" ng-model="active" ng-checked="active" ng-change="change1(request, active)"><br>
</td>
```

In js file

```
$scope.updateDataList = [];
$scope.change1 = function (request, active) {
    if (active) {
        $scope.updateDataList.push(request);
    }
    else {
        $scope.updateDataList.splice($scope.updateDataList.indexOf(request), 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: The check box creation is inside ng-repeat. Thats why I have used an array to store the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checkbox is ticked model assigned with 1, similarly for unchecked state model will have 0

```
 <td>
        <input name ="chk1[]" type="checkbox" ng-model="active" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-change="change1(request,active)"><br>
    </td>
```

For case when you wants the checkbox to be unchecked, just re-assign the model value with 0. 
Like `$scope.active = 0;`